# Setting Octave interpreter to 'tex'

Tags: octave, interpreter, tex

Such a simple question to have wasted an hour or two of my time. The Octave docs allude to setting the interpreter to tex and never say how to do it. I've looked on line and through stackoverflow and haven't found how to do this. I've also looked at the .octaverc files and have seen nothing that would indicate how to turn on the tex edit function. I am using Debian GNUOctave version 4.0.0. Please help.

Gary Roach

Comment: Are you trying to change the interpreter for a figure or text control?

Comment: Typically it's already set to "Tex" and you don't have to change it as far as you don't want to disable rendering with "none". And be aware that printing symbols in 4.0.0 only works with graphics_toolkit gnuplot

Answer (score 5):

The interpreter property is set to "tex" per default for axes, line, text, patch and surface. So changing interpreter makes only sense if you want to switch to "none":

```
set (findobj (gcf, "-property", "interpreter"), "interpreter", "none")
```

This sets "interpreter"="none" for al children of the current figure.

If you want to have some fancy latex stuff in your plots and not only simple tex commands you can render it with latex:

```
close all
graphics_toolkit fltk
sombrero ();
title ("The sombrero function:")
fcn = "$z = \\frac{\\sin\\left(\\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\right)}{\\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$";
text (0.5, -10, 1.8, fcn, "fontsize", 20);

print -depslatexstandalone sombrero

## process generated files with pdflatex
system ("latex sombrero.tex");

## dvi to ps
system ("dvips sombrero.dvi");

## convert to png
system ("gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r100x100 -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=sombrero.png sombrero.ps")
```

which gives:
[image: sombrero with latex]